# Propel multiple behaviors (e. i18n && versionable)

Tags: php, propel, behavior

I am trying out Propel and seeing if its acceptable for my project.

When combining multiple Behaviors, a certain behavior does not inherit other behaviors.

**Example schema.xml:**

```
<table name="item" phpName="Item">
    <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
    <column name="name" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />

    <behavior name="sluggable" />

    <behavior name="sortable" />

    <behavior name="i18n">
        <parameter name="i18n_columns" value="name" />
    </behavior>

    <behavior name="versionable">
        <parameter name="log_created_at" value="true" />
        <parameter name="log_created_by" value="true" />
        <parameter name="log_comment" value="true" />
    </behavior>
</table>
```

**Example controller:**

```
// create example records
$item = new Item();

// create version with i18n record
$item->setLocale('en_US');
$item->setName('Hello');
$item->save();

// create version with i18n record
$item->setLocale('is_IS');
$item->setName('World');
$item->save();

// get created newly created item
$item = ItemQuery::create()
  ->findPK(1);

foreach ($item->getAllVersions() as $itemVersion)
{
    echo 'us name: ' . $itemVersion->setLocale('en_US')->getName() . "\n";

    echo 'is name: ' . $itemVersion->setLocale('is_IS')->getName() . "\n";
}
```

This throws error that the method **setLocale()** does not exists, as we are positioned in the class "BaseItemVersion.php", which does not have any BaseItemI18n.php methods.

Is there any way to solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to solve this easily... The way behaviors work is that they add code to the base classes (and possible add tables/columns). The behaviors don't execute in isolation, but that doesn't mean that they'll be able to operate on each other - in other words, I'm not sure that the new table that `Versionable` adds would ever have the locale fields that `i18n` adds. You may want to search (or add this to) the issues on Github! https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/issues

Answer (score 0):

http://propelorm.org/behaviors/versionable.html

> Versioning of related objects is only possible for simple foreign keys. Relationships based on composite foreign keys cannot preserve relation versionning for now.

Since i18n adds complex foreign keys, the two won't work together.